# first online rails app not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to make a rails app, install unicorn, and install nginx. The tutorial says I should point my nginx.conf to `/home/myusername/my_app/public`, which is indeed where my public directory for my application is.

However, when I start unicorn and then start nginx I see a 403 forbidden error when going to `http://mypublicipaddress`. If I put an index.html page in my public directory, it displays fine. But without it, my routes.rb doesn't seem to rout. Here are the contents of my routs.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :tasks
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'welcome#index'

# Example of regular route:
#   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

# Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
#   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

# Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
#   resources :products

# Example resource route with options:
#   resources :products do
#     member do
#       get 'short'
#       post 'toggle'
#     end
#
#     collection do
#       get 'sold'
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments, :sales
#     resource :seller
#   end

# Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments
#     resources :sales do
#       get 'recent', on: :collection
#     end
#   end

# Example resource route with concerns:
#   concern :toggleable do
#     post 'toggle'
#   end
#   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
#   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

# Example resource route within a namespace:
#   namespace :admin do
#     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
#     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
#     resources :products
#   end
end
```

Since a regular index.html is showing it's not a permissions problem. What's happening here?

Comment: without a error message we can't help

Comment: what do you mean? the error message is 403 forbidden

Comment: nobody is interested in server error messages. we are interested in the logfile log/production.log

Comment: my tip: assets problem

Comment: Did you try to use this? root to: 'welcome#index'

Comment: Or it can be nginx error, try to open your server config and change (try_files $uri $uri/ @app;) to (try_files $uri @app;)